Bastion OST: Processing to achieve drum sound?
I'm very new to audio production.
I love the drum sounds in the songs from the Bastion video game sound track. E.g. https://spotify.link/RZhjOTSpUIb (but the whole album is kind of characterised by this crunchy hyper processed drum sound).
What kind of processing or filters produce this drum sound? To me, it feels heavily processed, I want to describe it as 'compressed' or squashed to a degree that digital processing artefacts are intentionally introduced. There also seems to be some flage-ey panning going on maybe? I don't have the technical vocabulary to know what I'm hearing or describing though.
Can someone with more experienced ears help me know what this type of processing is called, and how to reproduce it in a DAW with my own drum kit or vst?
Thank you!

I didn't hear anything all that crazy in the short clip you linked, but you can probably read up on saturation plugins and get some good insight.
